# Is it true that finishing the registration to the Android Market can take up to 4 days?

Tags: android, registration, google-play

I just registered my dev account in the Android Market and there is the message: **Your Registration to the Android Market is still being processed** . I googled and read around and I read that this phase can take up to 3-4 days! Is it true? How much time did it require for you?

Comment: mine was processed in minutes

Comment: I suspect that longer timeframe is if they have to manually process your credit card, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a minute. But please, ask such questions on the Android stackexchange: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

An hour I think, usually it doesn't take long.